# How to assign array within Redux AddCase fulfilled case

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, redux, interface

I am having a problem trying to figure out how assign an array of users after an async fetch. I have a simple interface User, which has an id and a name:

```js
export interface User {
  id: number
}
```

I then have a UserState that includes an array of users:

```js
export interface UserState {
  loading: boolean
  users: User[] 
  status: userStatus
  error: string | null | undefined
}
```

In my slice, I have an asychronous function:

```js
export const getUsers = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/fetchUsers',
  async (users: []) => {
      const response = await fetchUsers();
      return response.data;
  }
);
```

I don't have reducers but I do have extraReducers:

```js
const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder.addCase(getUsers.fulfilled, (state, {payload: users}) => {
            state.loading = false
            state.status = 'idle'
            state.users = users  //??? Or something like this...???
            state.error = ''
        })
    }        
})
```

For clarity, I've just included this one addCase where I am trying to assign the expected array of users in JSON format into the users array. I've tried a number of different syntax variations and I'm getting errors like:

> Type 'User[]' is not assignable to type '(() => Element)[]'.
> Type 'User' is not assignable to type '() => Element'.
> Type 'User' provides no match for the signature '(): Element'.ts(2322)

I'm not entirely sure how to address this one. I've looked at a number of tutorials and examples but there are many different ways of doing things. I'm not sure if I'm close to a solution -- there is a simple and direct fix from where I am -- or if I'm a world away from fixing this. I feel as if I've gone down too many rabbit holes and ended up creating a monster of mixed parts that don't quite fit together.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you maybe also have a `User` component and did you maybe accidentally import that one instead of your `User` interface at some point?

Comment: I do have a User component, as well, but I believe I'm importing the correct one (from the types definition file) here. I'm assuming the namespaces won't conflict...?

Comment: I can only tell you that `() => Element` really looks like a component definition and it is telling you that you are saving something that has the type `() => Element` instead of the expected `User` interface. So I would really double-check that.

Comment: You're right! I searched more carefully and found that I indeed did import the User component in addition to the interface. Thanks so much! If you put it as the solution, I'll close the case with it and give credit where it's due!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, it seems as if you are trying to assign a component type to the `User` interface here - it seems you have at some point been importing a `User` component instead of your `User` interface. Going through your imports and finding the wrong import will fix your problem.